# RoR: Selecting Certain Posts Based on a Column Value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have recently been trying to teach myself RoR. I have been working through some tutorials over the past few weeks, trying to add some of my own functionality to the app as I go. The feature I am trying to implement seems quite simple, but doubt my solution is as safe and elegant as it could be.

So far, users can submit a post to the site. The model consists of an image, title, category, and description. Users can also comment on a given post (the comments are contained in another table). I am trying to add a dropdown menu on the navigation bar that allows users to browse specific categories. In other words, the index should only display posts within the category that the user has selected. While my solution works, I am unhappy with it. Here is my code for the navigation bar:

```
%button#menu1.btn.btn-primary.dropdown-toggle{"data-toggle" => "dropdown", :type => "button"}
    Explore
    %span.caret
  %ul.dropdown-menu{"aria-labelledby" => "menu1", :role => "menu"}
    %li{:role => "presentation"}
      %a
        = link_to "All", posts_path(categories: "All")
    %li{:role => "presentation"}
      %a
        = link_to "3D Modeling", posts_path(categories: "3D Modeling")
    %li{:role => "presentation"}
      %a
        = link_to "Design", posts_path(categories: "Design")
    %li{:role => "presentation"}
      %a
        = link_to "Drawing", posts_path(categories: "Drawing")
    %li{:role => "presentation"}
      %a
        = link_to "Photography", posts_path(categories: "Photography")
    %li{:role => "presentation"}
      %a
        = link_to "Printmaking", posts_path(categories: "Printmaking")
    %li{:role => "presentation"}
      %a
        = link_to "Sculpture", posts_path(categories: "Sculpture")
    %li{:role => "presentation"}
      %a
        = link_to "Other", posts_path(categories: "Other")
```

Here is my code for the index method in the posts controller:

```
if params[:categories] && params[:categories] == "All"
  @posts = Post.all.order('created_at DESC').page params[:page]
elsif params[:categories] && params[:categories] == "3D Modeling"
  @posts = Post.where(category: "3D Modeling").page params[:page]
elsif params[:categories] && params[:categories] == "Design"
  @posts = Post.where(category: "Design").page params[:page]
elsif params[:categories] && params[:categories] == "Drawing"
  @posts = Post.where(category: "Drawing").page params[:page]
elsif params[:categories] && params[:categories] == "Photography"
  @posts = Post.where(category: "Photography").page params[:page]
elsif params[:categories] && params[:categories] == "Printmaking"
  @posts = Post.where(category: "Printmaking").page params[:page]
elsif params[:categories] && params[:categories] == "Sculpture"
  @posts = Post.where(category: "Sculpture").page params[:page]
elsif params[:categories] && params[:categories] == "Other"
  @posts = Post.where(category: "Other").page params[:page]
end
```

Finally, here is the code in my routes file:

```
resources :post do
    resources :comments do
end

root 'posts#index'
```

It seems as though I should be handling the routes differently? Or is that not the case since the category column is part of the post model and not its own table? Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
if params[:categories].present?
  @posts = Post.where(category: params[:categories]).page(params[:page])
else
  @posts = Post.all.order('created_at DESC').page(params[:page])
end
```

and remove the category of link_to with category: "All"

```
<%= link_to "All", posts_path %>
```

Comment: Yes! That did the trick. Thanks so much for taking the time to answer.